# Unable to use abstract state to provide initial shared views in Angular UI-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, abstract

I'm trying to provide some initial "partial" views through an abstract state using `Angular` and `Angular UI router` but somewhere along the way I'm making a misinterpretation which breaks my implementation...

As you can see I tried some variations with specifying a `customLayout.html` template to the abstract state. This also didn't work.

What **does** work (but isn't what I want) is specifying the shared partial templates on each state.

**I've implemented *that what does* and what *does not* here:**

> See this: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dekugupuru/edit?html,js,output).
>
> Look at: `//REMOVE COMMENT HERE` to switch between an "inherited" or "child" state.

```
        $stateProvider
            .state("layout", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "",
                //templateUrl: "customLayout.html",
                views: {
                    "header" :  {
                        templateUrl: 'shared/header.html',
                    }
                }
            })
            //REMOVE COMMENT HERE
            //.state("layout.demo")
            .state("demo", {
                url: "/demo",
                views: {
                    "" :  {
                        templateUrl: 'demo.html',
                    },
                    "header" :  {
                       templateUrl: 'shared/header.html'                            
                    }
                }
            });
```

Edit:

With help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38673380/45311):

```
    $stateProvider
            .state("layout", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "",
                //templateUrl: "customLayout.html",
                views: {
                    "header" :  {
                        templateUrl: 'shared/header.html',
                    },
                    //ADDED THIS, ESSENTIALLY PROXYING THE NAMELESS TEMPLATE
                    '': {
                        template: '<ui-view />'
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        console.log("app: states");

        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('/demo');


        $stateProvider
            .state("layout", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "",
                //templateUrl: "customLayout.html",
                views: {
                    "" :  {
                        templateUrl: 'demo.html'
                    },
                    "header" :  {
                        templateUrl: 'shared/header.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            //REMOVE COMMENT HERE
            //.state("layout.demo")
            .state("layout.demo", {
                url: "/demo",
            });
    }
]);
```

Here is the working link:
http://jsbin.com/zehejovaco/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Ah, this wasn't actually the solution because I want to specify the `demo.html` template on the `layout.demo` state obviously... However this did open my eyes! I now declared a new "intermediary" template on the `layout` abstract state for the nameless view with a template just specifying: `<ui-view />`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help!